# Getting latitude and longitude from address

Tags: php, google-maps

I can't figure out why I cannot get the coordinates from this address. 
Any help appreciated.

```
 <?php

function getCoordinates($address){
    $mapApiKey= 'AIzaSyBaEjohZpjSWkzIXQP0u01FZpZSe5Uxuhs';
    $address = urlencode($address);
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=" .$address ."&key=".$mapApiKey;
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response,true);
    $lat = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng = $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

 return array($lat, $lng);
  }

$coords = getCoordinates("Patras+Greece");
print_r($coords);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of file_get_contents use curl

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address."&sensor=false";
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                $response_a = json_decode($response);
                if(isset($response_a))
                {
                $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue using curl since wamp doesn't seem to enable it and 
I've tried to make it work in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* I have written this script for one of my recent project this works fine for me */


function get_latitude_longitude($address){
    $api_key = "Add your API Key"; // Replace with your Google Geocode API Key

    // Create the URL for the Geocoding API request
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($address) . "&key=" . $api_key;
    
    // Initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    
    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    // Execute cURL session and get the JSON response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);
    
    // Decode the JSON response
    $data = json_decode($response);

    // Check for status and retrieve lat-long
    if ($data->status == "OK") {
        $lat_lng['lat'] = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lat_lng['lng'] = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    } 
    return $lat_lng;
}

$latlong = get_latitude_longitude('your address here'); // call function for get latitude and longitude from address

echo 'latitude:-'.$latlong['lat'];

echo 'longitute:-'.$latlong['lat'];
```